# Format Data for Attribution Modeling in R

Tags: r, google-analytics

I am working on an attribution modeling problem at work and am having issues formatting the data.  I am using the following package:

```
install.packages("ChannelAttribution")
library(ChannelAttribution)
```

To use the functions in this package, I need the data in a specific format:
Example:

```
GooglePaid>Direct>GoogleOrganic>BingPaid>Converted
```

My desired output would look like this:

```
path                                               total_conversions          
Direct>GooglePaid>Converted                           504
GoogleOrganic>Direct>Direct>Direct                    689
YahooPaid>Converted                                   1,900
GoogleOrganic>BingPaid>Direct>Converted               785
```

Total conversions would be the sum of the number of times someone took that unique path.  So in the above example, Direct>GooglePaid>Converted was observed 504 times in the data set.

**However**

Here is my current data format from our development team:

```
 custID   custChannel            custDate
1  151        Direct        2015-10-10 00:15:32
2  151    GooglePaid        2015-10-10 00:16:45
3  151     Converted        2015-10-10 00:17:01
4  5655      BingPaid       2015-10-11 00:20:12
5  7855 GoogleOrganic       2015-10-12 00:05:32
6  7862  YahooOrganic       2015-10-13 00:18:20
7  9655    GooglePaid       2015-10-13 00:08:35
8  9655    GooglePaid       2015-10-13 00:11:11
9  9655     Converted       2015-10-13 00:11:35
```

In the above data, each unique path should sum to 1, since there is only one recorded path, but if we add this custID:

```
custID   custChannel            custDate
1  9666    GooglePaid        2015-10-14 00:15:32
2  9666    GooglePaid        2015-10-14 00:16:45
3  9666     Converted        2015-10-14 00:17:01
```

It would bring the GooglePaid>GooglePaid>Converted total to 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

("Provided by" the package or "needed as input-to" that package? Sounds like the latter.)

Sounds like you want to 1) paste the sequential values of custChannel with " > " as the separator and 2) also count them, both actions within distinct values of CustID. Cannot really tell what is the basis for either of "total_conversion_value" or "total_null".

I added a `custTime` variable, although it seems likely that you have either a fixed width-format or a tab-separated input format. (I would worry a bit about spaces given the funny offsets in the second column, since I suspect you did not use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` with whitespace as the implicit separator)

```
dat <- read.table(text=" custID   custChannel            custDate custTime
1  151        Direct        2015-10-10 00:15:32
2  151    GooglePaid        2015-10-10 00:16:45
3  151     Converted        2015-10-10 00:17:01
4  5655      BingPaid       2015-10-11 00:20:12
5  7855 GoogleOrganic       2015-10-12 00:05:32
6  7862  YahooOrganic       2015-10-13 00:18:20
7  9655    GooglePaid       2015-10-13 00:08:35
8  9655    GooglePaid       2015-10-13 00:11:11
9  9655     Converted       2015-10-13 00:11:35", header=TRUE, 
stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

If you are not getting this from your development team as sorted within customer data and time, then that can be done with `dat <- with(dat, dat[ order(custID, custDate, custTime), ] )`

```
dat2 <-  lapply(unique(dat$custID), 
  function(x)  list( path= paste(dat[dat$custID==x,'custChannel'],  sep="", collapse=">"), 
                     total_conversions= length( dat[dat$custID==x,'custChannel']) ) )

do.call('rbind', dat2)
#--------------
     path                              total_conversions
[1,] "Direct>GooglePaid>Converted"     3                
[2,] "BingPaid"                        1                
[3,] "GoogleOrganic"                   1                
[4,] "YahooOrganic"                    1                
[5,] "GooglePaid>GooglePaid>Converted" 3
```

Comment: This is actually great, but the output is slightly incorrect.  The output should for [5,] should be GooglePaid>GooglePaid>Converted  since there is only one instance of a customer (as identified by the custID) taking that path.  Same with [,1]

Total conversions would go up by one if in the data set we find another customer who took an identical journey as [1,] or [5,].  So for a data set of 5 million rows, one touch point path GooglePaid should have hundreds of thousands of "total Conversions"

Does that make sense?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You say [5,] should be `"GooglePaid>GooglePaid>Converted"` and that's exactly what it was. If you want to subtract one from total conversions or do something else then you need to offer a definiton of correct answer, which at the moment is lacking. If you want to run `table` over all the path columns and then match to values of path, that _might_ be what you comment suggests.

Comment: Excuse me, I meant [5,] should read GooglePaid>Google>Paid total conversions =1.  This there is only one recorded customer path like that.  I think my wording in the original posting was not correct.

Comment: Fix your question (with the edit feature). Define your terms. Stumbling around in Comments is not helping.

Comment: Does my revised question make sense now?

Comment: @BrandonB did you manage to solve the problem? If yes, can you please share the answer?